# Real-time anomaly detection

Tags: r, time-series, large-data

I would like to do anomaly detection in R on real-time stream of sensor data. I would like to explore use of either the Twitter [anomalyDetection](https://github.com/twitter/AnomalyDetection)  or [anomalous](https://github.com/robjhyndman/anomalous).

I am trying to think of the most efficient way to do this, as some online sources suggest R is not suitable for real-time anomaly detection. See [https://anomaly.io/anomaly-detection-twitter-r](https://anomaly.io/anomaly-detection-twitter-r/). Should I use the `stream` package to implement my own data stream source? If I do so, is there any "rule-of-thumb" as to how much data I should stream in order to have a sufficient amount of data (perhaps that is what I need to experiment with)? Is there any way of doing the anomaly detection in-database rather than in-application to speed things up?

Comment: Possibly, I am also seeking if there is a specialised stream processing algorithm for anomaly detection (e.g. should I create a new Data Stream Task implementation in using the "stream" package framework?

Comment: Me again (feeling a little lonely here). Any blogs/links/advice on integrating Apache storm with R package anomalyDetection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My experience is that if you want real time anomaly detection, you need to apply an online learning algorithm (rather than batch), ideally running on each sample as it is collected/generated. To do it, you would need to modify the existing open sources to run in online mode and adapt the model parameters for each sample that is processed. 
I'm not aware of an open source package that does it though.
For example, if you're computing a very simple anomaly detector, using the normal distribution, all you need to do is update the mean and variance of each metric with each sample that arrives. If you want the model to be adaptive, you'll need to add a forgetting factor (e.g., exponential forgetting), and control the "memory" of the mean and variance.
Another algorithm which lends itself to online learning is Holt-Winters. There is a several R-implementations of it, though you still have to make it run in online mode to be real time.

I gave a talk on this topic at the Big Data, Analytics & Applied Machine Learning - Israeli Innovation Conference last May. The video is at:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrOM2z6h_RQ
(DISCLAIMER: I am the chief data scientist for Anodot, a commercial company doing real time anomaly detection).

Comment: Thanks Ira. I viewed your talk which was very interesting and was wondering if you have any slides available that accompany the talk since the slides are not visible in the presentation.

Comment: I'll be happy to send the slides. my email is my first name at company name .com